# Copying over files from multiple directories into one folder

Tags: r

I'm looking to copy a set of files from multiple directories into one new folder using this code:

```
file.copy(from = paste0('directory1', all_files),
          to = paste0('directory2', all_files))
```

`all_files` is a character vector of files including their full path location.
I've also tried using basename(all_files) with no luck.

I've tried using the code above

Comment: You may need `file.path`.  Not clear about the contents of `all_files`

Comment: "with no luck" means ? Were there any error or warning messages, or the code seemed to run OK but with no result?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, it returns FALSE for every object in the character vector

Answer (score 1):

Just following up - I've figured it out.

It wasn't working because the paste was redundant, this code fixed it:

```
for (n in 1:length(all_files)) {
  file.copy(from = all_files[n],
           to = 'directory2')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the below code, in the to argument we need to use the new folder path where the files need to the copied over

```r
file.copy(from = paste0('directory1', all_files),
          to = directory2)
```

Comment: This is still an error. If all_files contains a path like `C:/folder1/subfolder2/file.ext` then pasting `'directory1'` in front of it would yield an incorrect path